# Efficiently change elements in data based on neighbouring elements

Tags: r

Let me delve right in. Imagine you have data that looks like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(one = c(1, 1, NA, 13), 
                  two = c(2, NA,10, 14), 
                three = c(NA,NA,11, NA), 
                 four = c(4, 9, 12, NA))
```

This gives us:

```
df
#   one two three four
# 1   1   2    NA    4
# 2   1  NA    NA    9
# 3  NA  10    11   12
# 4  13  14    NA   NA
```

Each row are measurements in week 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively. Suppose the numbers represent some accumulated measure since the last time a measurement happened. For example, in row 1, the "4" in column "four" represents a cumulative value of week 3 and 4.

Now I want to "even out" these numbers (feel free to correct my terminology here) by evenly spreading out the measurements to all weeks before the measurement if no measurement took place in the preceeding weeks. For instance, row 1 should read

```
 1 2 2 2
```

since the 4 in the original data represents the cumulative value of 2 weeks (week "three" and "four"), and 4/2 is 2.

The final end result should look like this:

```
df
#  one two three four
# 1   1   2    2    2
# 2   1   3    3    3
# 3   5   5   11   12
# 4  13  14   NA   NA
```

I struggle a bit with how to best approach this. One candidate solution would be to get the indices of all missing values, then to count the length of runs (NAs occuring multiple times), and use that to fill up the values somehow. However, my real data is large, and I think such a strategy might be time consuming. Is there an easier and more efficient way?

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted? It's a clear reproducible question with effort at thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A base R solution would be to first identify the indices that need to be replaced, then determine groupings of those indices, finally assigning grouped values with the `ave` function:

```
clean <- function(x) {
  to.rep <- which(is.na(x) | c(FALSE, head(is.na(x), -1)))
  groups <- cumsum(c(TRUE, head(!is.na(x[to.rep]), -1)))
  x[to.rep] <- ave(x[to.rep], groups, FUN=function(y) {
    rep(tail(y, 1) / length(y), length(y))
  })
  return(x)
}
t(apply(df, 1, clean))
#      one two three four
# [1,]   1   2     2    2
# [2,]   1   3     3    3
# [3,]   5   5    11   12
# [4,]  13  14    NA   NA
```

If efficiency is important (your question implies it is), then an Rcpp solution could be a good option:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
"NumericVector cleanRcpp(NumericVector x) {
  const int n = x.size();
  NumericVector y(x);
  int consecNA = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (R_IsNA(x[i])) {
      ++consecNA;
    } else if (consecNA > 0) {
      const double replacement = x[i] / (consecNA + 1);
      for (int j=i-consecNA; j <= i; ++j) {
        y[j] = replacement;
      }
      consecNA = 0;
    } else {
      consecNA = 0;
    }
  }
  return y;
}")
t(apply(df, 1, cleanRcpp))
#      one two three four
# [1,]   1   2     2    2
# [2,]   1   3     3    3
# [3,]   5   5    11   12
# [4,]  13  14    NA   NA
```

We can compare performance on a larger instance (10000 x 100 matrix):

```
set.seed(144)
mat <- matrix(sample(c(1:3, NA), 1000000, replace=TRUE), nrow=10000)
all.equal(apply(mat, 1, clean), apply(mat, 1, cleanRcpp))
# [1] TRUE
system.time(apply(mat, 1, clean))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.918   0.035   4.992 
system.time(apply(mat, 1, cleanRcpp))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.093   0.016   0.120
```

In this case the Rcpp solution provides roughly a 40x speedup compared to the base R implementation.

Comment: I'm surprised how difficult this problem is. It seems like there should be a simple couple line answer, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: @thelatemail just updated with a not-too-awfully-long base R solution.

Comment: Looks good. Don't think I could do any better. 5 seconds for 10k x 10k is still pretty quick. It would probably spiral out of control with a HUGE table though. :-)

Comment: Blah 10k x 100; I cannot count zeroes.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a base R solution that's *nearly* as fast as josilber's Rcpp function:

```
spread_left <- function(df) {
    nc <- ncol(df)
    x <- rev(as.vector(t(as.matrix(cbind(df, -Inf)))))
    ii <- cumsum(!is.na(x))
    f <- tabulate(ii)
    v <- x[!duplicated(ii)]
    xx <- v[ii]/f[ii]
    xx[xx == -Inf] <- NA
    m <- matrix(rev(xx), ncol=nc+1, byrow=TRUE)[,seq_len(nc)]
    as.data.frame(m)
}
spread_left(df)
#   one two three four
# 1   1   2     2    2
# 2   1   3     3    3
# 3   5   5    11   12
# 4  13  14    NA   NA
```

It manages to be relatively fast by vectorizing everything and completely avoiding time-expensive calls to `apply()`. (The downside is that it's also relatively obfuscated; to see how it works, do `debug(spread_left)` and then apply it to the small data.frame `df` in the OP.

Here are benchmarks for all currently posted solutions:

```
library(rbenchmark)
set.seed(144)
mat <- matrix(sample(c(1:3, NA), 1000000, replace=TRUE), nrow=10000)
df <- as.data.frame(mat)

## First confirm that it produces the same results
identical(spread_left(df), as.data.frame(t(apply(mat, 1, clean)))) 
# [1] TRUE

## Then compare its speed
benchmark(josilberR     = t(apply(mat, 1, clean)),
          josilberRcpp  = t(apply(mat, 1, cleanRcpp)),
          Josh          = spread_left(df),
          Henrik        = t(apply(df, 1, fn)),
          replications = 10)
#           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 4       Henrik           10   38.81   25.201     38.74     0.08
# 3         Josh           10    2.07    1.344      1.67     0.41
# 1    josilberR           10   57.42   37.286     57.37     0.05
# 2 josilberRcpp           10    1.54    1.000      1.44     0.11
```

Comment: Great answer! I accepted josilbers answer since he was the first, included the most efficient (Rcpp) solution and had the most upvotes, but I learned a lot from your solution, Josh! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Josh O'Brien Thanks for adding the benchmark and for a great answer (++). I will really step through both your alternatives. Impressed by the speed both of them. Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks! Because it was in all ways inferior, I've now removed my first solution. (If you still want to look at it, as it did include some tricky vectorizations of its own, you should be able to access it via the edit history.)

Comment: Just noticed that you test `identical` against a `Josh2` function that is not defined here.

Comment: @Frank Thanks. Fixed it. (I had two functions up for a while, but have removed my initial attempt, as it was quite a bit less efficient -- and even less expressive(!) -- than the one that remains.)

Answer (score 7):

Another `base` possibility. I first create a grouping variable (grp), over which the 'spread' is then made with `ave`.

```
fn <- function(x){
  grp <- rev(cumsum(!is.na(rev(x))))
  res <- ave(x, grp, FUN = function(y) sum(y, na.rm = TRUE) / length(y))
  res[grp == 0] <- NA
  res
}

t(apply(df, 1, fn))
#      one two three four
# [1,]   1   2     2    2
# [2,]   1   3     3    3
# [3,]   5   5    11   12
# [4,]  13  14    NA   NA
```

Comment: Brilliant -- the idea of treating consecutive non-missing elements as 1-element groups makes this much simpler!

Comment: @josilber Thanks! Of course, when each row contain many non-missing values, it will be less efficient `ave`-ing over all these groups. But yes, generating the groups like this in the first place involves few operations.

Comment: @josilber Interestingly, that's what my code does as well (though I know my vectorization of large chunks of the code make that *quite* hard to see without debugging and stepping through with a small example)!

Comment: Cool approach. Thanks for your answer Henrik!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien ah, I can see it more easily with the second one. Nice approach!

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking that if `NA`s are relatively rare, it might be better to make the edits by reference. (I'm guessing this is how the Rcpp approach works.) Here's how it can be done in `data.table`, borrowing @Henrik's function almost verbatim and converting to long format:

```
require(data.table) # 1.9.5
fill_naseq <- function(df){

    # switch to long format
    DT  <- data.table(id=(1:nrow(df))*ncol(df),df)
    mDT <- setkey(melt(DT,id.vars="id"),id)
    mDT[,value := as.numeric(value)]

    mDT[,badv  := is.na(value)]     
    mDT[
      # subset to rows that need modification
      badv|shift(badv),
      # apply @Henrik's function, more or less
      value:={
        g = ave(!badv,id,FUN=function(x)rev(cumsum(rev(x))))+id
        ave(value,g,FUN=function(x){n = length(x); x[n]/n})
    }]

    # revert to wide format
    (setDF(dcast(mDT,id~variable)[,id:=NULL]))
}

identical(fill_naseq(df),spread_left(df)) # TRUE
```

To show the best-case scenario for this approach, I simulated so that `NA`s are very infrequent:

```
nr = 1e4
nc = 100
nafreq = 1/1e4

mat <- matrix(sample(
  c(NA,1:3),
  nr*nc, 
  replace=TRUE,
  prob=c(nafreq,rep((1-nafreq)/3,3))
),nrow=nr)
df  <- as.data.frame(mat)

benchmark(F=fill_naseq(df),Josh=spread_left(df),replications=10)[1:5]
#   test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 1    F           10    3.82    1.394      3.72
# 2 Josh           10    2.74    1.000      2.70
# I don't have Rcpp installed and so left off josilber's even faster approach
```

So, it's still slower. However, with data kept in a long format, reshaping wouldn't be necessary:

```
DT  <- data.table(id=(1:nrow(df))*ncol(df),df)
mDT <- setkey(melt(DT,id.vars="id"),id)
mDT[,value := as.numeric(value)]

fill_naseq_long <- function(mDT){
    mDT[,badv := is.na(value)]
    mDT[badv|shift(badv),value:={
      g = ave(!badv,id,FUN=function(x)rev(cumsum(rev(x))))+id
      ave(value,g,FUN=function(x){n = length(x); x[n]/n})
    }]
    mDT
}

benchmark(
  F2=fill_naseq_long(mDT),F=fill_naseq(df),Josh=spread_left(df),replications=10)[1:5]
#   test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 2    F           10    3.98    8.468      3.81
# 1   F2           10    0.47    1.000      0.45
# 3 Josh           10    2.72    5.787      2.69
```

Now it's a little faster. And who doesn't like keeping their data in long format? This also has the advantage of working even if we don't have the same number of observations per "id".

Comment: I'm not sure if the last bit of benchmarking is kosher, since it's modifying `mDT` by reference at each iteration. I'm open to suggestions/corrections.